Percentage of specific subgroup based on bucket field on parent level
I hope you can help me with the following target to enrich my existing Salesforce report. I am using Salesforce Classic.
Current report layout:
Group 1: Yearly (last 10 years)
Group 2: BucketField (resulting in three categories - A,B,C)

My target is to achieve a formula which shows the percentage of records of a single specific subgroup (Group 2) on the yearly summary group line.
Thus the result on group level 1 would basically look like this:
2020 - RowCount 20 - Total Amount 123 USD - %Ratio: 34%
2021 - RowCount 18 - Total Amount 234 USD - %Ratio: 44%
2022 - RowCount 25 - Total Amount 432 USD - %Ratio: 50%
...

In pseudo-code the field formula on the yearly level (group 1) would look like this:
RowCount of Group 2 value "A" / RowCount of Group 1 value (per year)

Until now I managed to show only the overall percentages on the group 2 level. But I am stuck to evaluate the rowcount of a specific subgroup based on a bucket field.
I am quite new to salesforce formulas, thus any help to achieve this is highly appreciated.
Thanks all for your help.
All the best,
faiko
